# Install XCode on Lion fresh install

Tags: macos, xcode

I just received a new Mac, shipping with Lion. There is no install CD or DVD. Where is Xcode ? Do I have to use the App Store and create an Apple ID to get it? 
What about X11 ?

Answer (score 6):

Correct. Xcode is only available via the App Store to non developers [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12). Registering an Apple ID is free and any email address can be used.

Alternatively, if you are a registered developer you can download the DMG from the Developer site [here](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/)*

X11 is still a standard part of the Lion installation.

Also, note when registering an Apple ID for the App Store you are not required to provide credit card details as seen below. The option for none is available.

[image: Credit Card Options]

<sub>* Developer Account Required</sub>

Comment: @StefanoBorini Apple is one of the few companies I have no issue registering with. I have yet to receive spam from them, and having an Apple ID makes my life infinitely easier all round, especially if you own a huge amount of Apple devices.

Comment: I can't create an account on the app store because I don't have a credit card. How can I download Xcode ?

Comment: @StefanoBorini You don't need a credit card. When you register there should be an option for none.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Updated my answer to show the credit card options I see in the ZA and US accounts. The US accounts also allow for PayPal.

Comment: I see no None option, even after changing to US for the billing address.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Sorry. Not sure then. I looked at both the US and ZA App Stores and the none option is definitely visible for me.

Comment: Apple provides instructions for Creating an iTunes App Store account without a credit card at  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534 (Note that you have to follow the steps in a Very Specific Order for it to work.)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you now need a credit card to get access to the App store. As of Dec 5, 2011, I see no "None" option. Either it has changed recently, or it depends on your IP's geographic location. Changing the "billing country" does change a few payment options, but after trying a few different countries, including the US, there is still no possibility to continue without a CC or equivalent service.

However, if you have an ID giving you access to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/, you can search for Xcode there. I was able to download [xcode_4.2.1_for_lion.dmg](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2.1_for_lion/xcode_4.2.1_for_lion.dmg) with my free Apple ID without updating it to add a credit card.

I hope this is not a "loophole" they will quickly "fix"!

Also note that this "installer" is at least as misleading as the one from the App store. After you have downloaded and opened the usual .dmg file, you see the expected .pkg file: "InstallXcodeLion.pkg". But after you have done the full standard install of that .pkg, nothing is actually installed! You only "installed" the real installer: "/Applications/Install Xcode.app".